# python cant get a value after return

Tags: python

```
a=input("give me the integer")
result=""
def int_to_roman(a):

    if type(a) != type(1):
      raise TypeError, "expected integer, got %s" % type(a)
    if not 0 < a < 1000000:
      raise ValueError, "Argument must be between 1 and 1000000"
      ints = (1000, 900,  500, 400, 100,  90, 50,  40, 10,  9,   5,  4,   1)
      nums = ('M',  'CM', 'D', 'CD','C', 'XC','L','XL','X','IX','V','IV','I')
      result=""
    for i in range(len(ints)):
      result=""
      count = int(a / ints[i])
      result += nums[i] * count
      a -= ints[i] * count
      return result
      print("the result is " + result)
```

guys it says that in the end result is not defined can anyone explain to me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are the last two lines indented incorrectly? As is, for for loop will terminate after one iteration and your print statement is unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm correct about how your code is meant to be indented, and that you've omitted a line in which you actually invoke the function, the problem is that you're not allowed to modify global variables in function scope without declaring them global. So just add `global result` to the top of the function if you want to be able to read `result` after the function is executed.

This is generally a terrible idea, though – it's much better to just assign the result of the function to a value, like

```
result = int_to_roman(a)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to unindent the lines after the return in the second if statement.

```
if type(a) != type(1):
  raise TypeError, "expected integer, got %s" % type(a)
if not 0 < a < 1000000:
  raise ValueError, "Argument must be between 1 and 1000000"
ints = (1000, 900,  500, 400, 100,  90, 50,  40, 10,  9,   5,  4,   1)
nums = ('M',  'CM', 'D', 'CD','C', 'XC','L','XL','X','IX','V','IV','I')
result=""
for i in range(len(ints)):
  result=""
  count = int(a / ints[i])
  result += nums[i] * count
  a -= ints[i] * count
print("the result is " + result)
return result
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this hasn't fixed all of the indentation problems – there's still an unconditional return in the loop, and an unreachable print after it.